# Unable to compile java 21

Tags: java, java-21

I saw in java 21 , you don't need to write public static in you main method and you can just write

```
public class Main{
    void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

I uninstalled java 17 and installed java 21 , added it to the environment variables but when I am running this code , I am getting this error.

```
Error: Main method not found in class Main, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application 
]
```

When I am writing java --version in cmd , I am getting the version of my java as 21 but still the code is not compiling

Comment: The question to ask yourself and go a level deeper is, how are you compiling the code and what is the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[*Unnamed classes*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/445) is a [preview feature](https://openjdk.org/jeps/12), which means it doesn't exist unless you opt in: It's not meant for production code and is likely to break in a future release, hence why you must opt in:

```
javac --release 21 --enable-preview MyFile.java
java --enable-preview myFile
```

Comment: Or just `java --source 21 --enable-preview MyFile.java` to compile and run.